# SignalR, WebApi, Autofac, camelCasedJson

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, signalr, autofac

I Have a web api app, inluding some SignalR functionality that has it's dependencies managed by Autofac.

SignalR, out of the box, does not support camelCased Json properties.

There's a decent fix [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2013/11/28/automatic-camel-casing-of-properties-with-signalr-hubs-signalr-v2.aspx), but I need to integrate it with Autofac.

So.....

Here's the SignalR hub

```
 public class PledgeHub : Hub
{
    public void SendPledge(LivePledgeUpdate pledge)
    {
        Clients.All.sendPledge(pledge);
    }
}
```

Here's the startup.cs class inluding the Camelcased Resolver from the article

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Filanthropy.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        private readonly HttpConfiguration config;

        public Startup()
        {
            config = new HttpConfiguration();
        }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = BuildContainer(config);

            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            ConfigureAuth(app);

            ConfigureWebApi(config);

            app.MapSignalR();          

            app.UseWebApi(config);

            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);            
    }



        private void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();


        }

        private static IContainer BuildContainer(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
           var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register your Web API controllers.
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

            builder.RegisterType<PledgeHub>().ExternallyOwned();           

            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => JsonSerializerFactory.Value);

            return builder.Build();
    }


        private static readonly Lazy<JsonSerializer> JsonSerializerFactory = new Lazy<JsonSerializer>(GetJsonSerializer);

        private static JsonSerializer GetJsonSerializer()
        {
            return new JsonSerializer
            {
                ContractResolver = new FilteredCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
                {

                    TypesToInclude =
                                {
                                    typeof(SignalRHubs.PledgeHub),
                                }
                }
            };
        }


    }
}
```

I get camelCased properties just fine with everything that's served via WebApi, but not via Signalr.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your problem is this:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => JsonSerializerFactory.Value);
```

If you're using Autofac as the container / dependency resolver, you want to register the serializer with Autofac, not with the soon-to-be-replaced global dependency resolver.

```
builder.Register(ctx => JsonSerializerFactory.Value).As<JsonSerializer>();
```

Also, I see you're using OWIN. When you use OWIN, you don't reference `GlobalHost` - you set up your hub configuration separately. [The docs have an example showing how to do it](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html#owin-integration):

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // STANDARD SIGNALR SETUP:

    // Get your HubConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
    // rather than using GlobalHost.
    var config = new HubConfiguration();

    // Register your SignalR hubs.
    builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
    var container = builder.Build();
    config.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

    // OWIN SIGNALR SETUP:

    // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the standard SignalR middleware.
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It might be a couple of days before i'm near my computer to check the results and mark as correct. I knew it'd be something to do with the globalhost, just wasn't sure of the syntax to register that serializer

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It registers allright, but the serializer seems to mess up the communication. As soon as I've got the serializer in between, messages from the host don't make it to the clients any more. @MrBliz can you share whether you got this fixed or not?

Comment: I didn't. I ended up pascal casing on the client